# Trying to add multiple items, getting an inconstant result

Tags: jquery, addition

I am trying to add multiple div's to a page through a dropdown.

The problem I have:

```
var antal =  $('.room-holder').size();
var roomholder = '<div class="room-holder">' + $('.room-holder').html() + '</div>';
var rooms = "";

while ( $( this ).val() > ( antal + 0 ) ) {
    rooms = rooms + roomholder;
    antal++;
}

$( rooms ).insertAfter( $('.room-holder') );
rooms = "";
```

I have also tried with a for loop like this:

```
var many = ( $( this ).val() - antal );

for( i=0; i < many; i++){
    rooms = rooms + roomholder;
}

$( rooms ).insertAfter( $('.room-holder') );
antal =  $('.room-holder').size();
rooms = "";
```

The dropdown have the values from 1 - 10

When i select the first time i get the right number of fields, but when i select a second time i get like the amount it should add plus 2-3 fields.

Anyone know why?

edit: I added it to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmKJw/

Comment: can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Is that the body of an event handler function? If so, can we see the code to bind the event handler and the full (relevant) function declaration - would have been a lot more obvious what `this` in the code was then. Also the HTML for the dropdown would be good.

Comment: Please could you edit your question and add the full JavaScript function and how it is being called? Knowing what `this` is will be _very_ useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is the rooms to be inserted was getting appended to every `roomholder` already present.
Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ejbra/4/)

The fix is to append to new `room-holder` after the last `room-holder`

Change

```
$( rooms ).insertAfter( $('.room-holder') );
```

to

```
$( rooms ).insertAfter( $('.room-holder:last') );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ejbra/3/)

Answer (score 0):

A possible logic error here arises if the number of rooms you select in the drop-down is less than the number of rooms currently displayed. I would propose the following solution (which includes other stylistic improvements):

```
var numRoomsReqd = parseInt( $(this).val(), 10);
var numCurrRooms =  $('.room-holder').length;        // use length, not size
var $roomholder = $('.room-holder').first().clone();
var $rooms = $();
$('.room-holder').slice(numRoomsReqd).remove()

while ( numCurrRooms < numRoomsReqd ) {
    $rooms = $rooms.add($roomholder.clone());
    numCurrRooms++;
}

$rooms.insertAfter( $('.room-holder').last() );
```